# Issue using NULL in C files on Vim w/ Syntastic

Tags: c, gcc, vim, editor, syntastic

Heyo!

I have been using the Syntastic syntax checker plugin for a little while and have been really enjoying the experience except one irritating bug I cannot seem to figure out how to eliminate.

Every time I try to use NULL in my C programs, I get an error signified by the red "**>>**" and an error bubble saying `"use of undeclared identifier 'NULL' [undefined:]"`

[image: >>Link to screenshot of issue<<]

I have no issues using header files and the program compiles without any issues. It's just visually quite irritating to see a bunch of error flags when I am trying to implement data structures that use NULL pointers or NULL to signify free space.

I am using the gcc compiler and have set the compile options in my vimrc to:

```
let g:syntastic_c_compiler_options= '-std=c18'
```

(nothing changes if I remove the line from my vimrc and let it fall back to the default `-gnu99` as set by the  syntactic syntax-checkers config files in `~/.vim/plugged/syntastic/syntax_checkers/c/gcc.vim`)

Output of `:SyntasticInfo`:

```
Syntastic version: 3.10.0-7 (Vim 802, Linux, GUI)
Info for filetype: c
Global mode: active
Filetype c is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Available checkers: gcc make
Currently enabled checkers: gcc
```

Was hoping someone on here had dealt with a similar issue or had some ideas for a workaround.

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT 1:** Syntastic configuration commands in `.vimrc`

```
"Syntastic settings

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

"C Settings

let g:syntastic_c_compiler = 'gcc'
let g:syntastic_c_checkers=['gcc']
let g:syntastic_c_include_dirs=['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include']
let g:syntastic_c_auto_refresh_includes = 1
let g:syntastic_c_compiler_options= '-std=c18'
let g:syntastic_c_check_header = 1
```

Adding this to aid in diagnosis, must say thank you very much to everyone giving their input and trying to help me out!

**EDIT 2:**

I edited the compiler options to :

```
let g:syntastic_c_compiler_options= '-I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include -Wall -std=c18'
```

based on a suggestion from @user3629249. Now the undeclared identifier 'NULL' error shows up in the :Errors window (this can be attributed to the `-Wall` flag). But progress is progress :). Just need to understand how to configure Syntastic to understand NULL is actually defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: Can you list a small full program that reproduces this? Do you have an explicit include for `#include <stddef.h>`? If not, can you add it and see if it fixes the warning? If you build your code passing gcc an extra `-Wall` flag, do you see the same warning?

Comment: Syntastic's default settings are meaningless, you really need to adapt them to your project.  For `gcc` you need to tell syntastic to use the same options that you're using to compile the file.  See `:h syntastic-debug` for more information.

Comment: @filbranden
Hey! Thanks for the response! 
It makes no differences whether I include stddef.h or not. The program has no problem compiling even with -Wall flag. Zero warnings or errors from the compiler. This appears to be something wrong with syntastic. For example I can open the same file in Visual Studio Code and I do not see any syntax errors. I can even peek the reference for NULL and see that it is defined in <stddef.h>.

Comment: @lcd047 Hey! Appreciate the quick response. I did read the debug doc earlier and am giving it another read now. I am not  using any compiler flags at the moment when I compile my program as they are just little programs for practice. In my .vimrc file I have the recommended configuration lines and a couple more I added in attempts to fix this issue (auto_refresh_includes, check_header, and std=c11). As per my SyntasticInfo report it seems to be recognising and using gcc just fine. Is there something more specific I need to configure? Sorry If I didn't interpret your response correctly.

Comment: You need to configure syntastic to use the exact same command you use when you compile the file.  Otherwise you'll get different results, and you'll blame syntastic for it. :) Syntastic is a Vim script, it doesn't know (nor particularly cares) about C syntax.  It's all about how you tell syntastic to run `gcc`, nothing more, nothing less.  To see the command line constructed by syntastic you need to enable debugging and look at the logs.

Comment: @lcd047 Again I really appreciate your help!
I hope I didn't sound like I was blaming syntastic, that's definitely not my intention :). My experience with the plugin has been really great. It works  well for me and behaves as expected in C files except for in this one case when I am trying to use `NULL` .
I have set `let g:syntastic_c_compiler = 'gcc' `  in my `vimrc`. I hope this is what you meant. I understand you are saying I should forward all my compile flags to syntastic but I am not using any additional flags and gcc doesn't mind NULL. Did you mean I should path to the header files?

Comment: if you don't tell syntastic where to find the header files, then there will be lots of issues.

Comment: regarding: `let g:syntastic_c_compiler_options= '-std=c18'`  This does not enable the warnings for the compiler.  Suggest: `let g:syntastic_c_compiler_options= '-ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c18'`   The `-ggdb3` will optimize the output for the `gdb` (or `ddd`) debugger

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the insight, I will try this now. 

Another behavior of the issue I observed is that the NULL related undefined error doesn't show up in the :Errors window. It works fine for other errors like for example syntax errors such as not terminating with a semi colon. Just an observation.

Comment: @user3629249 


Giving a direct path to the stddef.h file didn't seem to help. I tested adding 'make' to the checkers list to see if it was reading it. The change was reflected in :SyntasticInfo so it appears it's reading the config commands just fine. I added all my config commands for Syntastic to the original post, perhaps it can help. Thanks again!

Comment: Please don’t put the tags into the title; it’s completely redundant: that’s what *tags* are for.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sorry bud, still developing my etiquette, it's my first post. Figured I should stop lurking and get more directly involved.

Comment: @shallow_learning Absolutely nothing to apologise for!

Comment: regarding: `'/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/include'`  That is the includes for compiling the OS.  I would expect your statement to be: `/usr/include`

Comment: That is the only location I could find where stddef.h . I tried copying it into the standard include directory as you suggested and sure enough, no longer getting bugged about using NULL!


Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to be the `stddef.h` file was not being accessed by Syntastic as it was deep in a `gcc` folder (see above) and not in the `/usr/include`. Making a copy of `stddef.h` and placing it in `/usr/include` seems to have resolved the issue I was having regarding the usage of `NULL`. Hopefully this won't create any further issues ;D.

Thanks again to everyone for their input and I hope this can save someone some headache in the future :).

Comment: If you could compile the file without errors the problem is still that syntastic builds a different command line than you use for that file.  Meaning, you'll probably run into the same issue again. _shrug_

Comment: I realised this, I will work on doing it the less lazy way soon.